# Is it possible to ignore video element underneath sticky navbar to enable links?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm a total beginner and I'm trying to make my first website.

My problem is that when I scroll down the website and the navbar is "over" the video element, the navbar links stop functioning. I assume this may have something to do with the video element taking precedence over the sticky navbar links. However, if I replace the video element with a box or an image, the navbar links work even when the navbar is over the video. Could someone please try to explain where I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

```css
body {
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0.7rem;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.header-item {
    margin-right: 5rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.banner {
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

video.banner-video {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    object-fit: fill;

}


.jumbo {
    padding-left: 4rem;
    padding-right: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

a.anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -8rem;
}


footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<head>
 <title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
</head>

<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="header-item" >Lorem Ipsum</li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-1">lorem</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-2">ipsum</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-3">dolor</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <section class="banner">
  <video class="banner-video" width="100%" height="320" loop muted autoplay>
   <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/357105171.sd.mp4?s=58a7816e7bd115bb9c452293741c393a1acb61e8&profile_id=139&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
 </section>
  
 <section class="jumbo">
  <a class="anchor" id="header-1"></a>
  <h2>lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea invee iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
  
  <a class="anchor" id="header-2"></a>
  <h2>Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <a class="anchor" id="header-3"></a>
  <h2>Dolor</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
 </section>

 <footer>
  <div>
   <p>&copy; 2020 cybele</p>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be working from your example fiddle... But to answer your question, yes it is possible: look into z-index CSS property.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. But when I position the navbar "above" the video and try to press for example "dolor", it doesn't jump down the page. However, if I position the navbar above a paragraph for example, it works.

Comment: But thank you, I'll take a look at the z-index, thanks!

(edit: I tried giving the video a z-index of -1, however the issue still persists :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, I forgot Firefox reads this properly almost always without z-index declared. Other including Chrome and Safari do not. You need z-index CSS property.

Just add z-index: 99; for example to your nav element so it will be allways on top of everything.
Also take note z-index does not work on elements that do not have position declared. . [Read more about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```css
body {
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0.7rem;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
    z-index: 99;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.header-item {
    margin-right: 5rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.banner {
    padding-top: 2rem;
}

video.banner-video {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    object-fit: fill;

}


.jumbo {
    padding-left: 4rem;
    padding-right: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

a.anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -8rem;
}


footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<head>
 <title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
</head>

<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="header-item" >Lorem Ipsum</li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-1">lorem</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-2">ipsum</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-3">dolor</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <section class="banner">
  <video class="banner-video" width="100%" height="320" loop muted autoplay>
   <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/357105171.sd.mp4?s=58a7816e7bd115bb9c452293741c393a1acb61e8&profile_id=139&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
 </section>
  
 <section class="jumbo">
  <a class="anchor" id="header-1"></a>
  <h2>lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea invee iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
  
  <a class="anchor" id="header-2"></a>
  <h2>Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <a class="anchor" id="header-3"></a>
  <h2>Dolor</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
 </section>

 <footer>
  <div>
   <p>&copy; 2020 cybele</p>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a position to your banner and a -1 z-index like this

```
.banner {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    z-index:-1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Here's it working

```css
body {
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

nav {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0.7rem;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 2rem;
}

.header-item {
    margin-right: 5rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.banner {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

video.banner-video {
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    object-fit: fill;

}


.jumbo {
    padding-left: 4rem;
    padding-right: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

a.anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -8rem;
}


footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<head>
 <title>Lorem ipsum dolor</title>
</head>

<body>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li class="header-item" >Lorem Ipsum</li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-1">lorem</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-2">ipsum</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#header-3">dolor</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

 <section class="banner">
  <video class="banner-video" width="100%" height="320" loop muted autoplay>
   <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/357105171.sd.mp4?s=58a7816e7bd115bb9c452293741c393a1acb61e8&profile_id=139&oauth2_token_id=57447761" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
 </section>
  
 <section class="jumbo">
  <a class="anchor" id="header-1"></a>
  <h2>lorem</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea invee iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
  
  <a class="anchor" id="header-2"></a>
  <h2>Ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <a class="anchor" id="header-3"></a>
  <h2>Dolor</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea inventore iste a similique. Voluptatum eum rem incidunt illo nam commodi, ad sit ex alias expedita a voluptas tempore minus veritatis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptatem quo alias, porro quaerat veniam dolorum consequuntur cupiditate illo ipsum impedit error ad eveniet iste accusantium excepturi temporibus natus doloribus ratione. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non dolore alias asperiores amet sequi ipsum enim consequuntur explicabo id, sunt hic voluptate autem molestiae nemo deleniti fugit, distinctio ut vel? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam repudiandae dolores soluta voluptatibus, odit autem repellat placeat voluptas accusantium nobis, blanditiis tempora, sit minima dolorem impedit aut illum aspernatur? Placeat.

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore vero ea, cupiditate, iure culpa fugit quibusdam aliquam iste officiis soluta recusandae deleniti eligendi mollitia molestias, sed explicabo exercitationem reiciendis? Obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio nulla sequi totam voluptatibus cumque dignissimos aliquid blanditiis saepe eius hic? Vel corrupti facere maxime officia aliquam ea, dolorum aperiam odio? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus voluptas itaque unde ab, culpa reiciendis omnis rerum harum atque ex recusandae excepturi voluptatem reprehenderit enim sit, odio deleniti ipsa ut? Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, pariatur voluptates tenetur officiis quam architecto placeat, mollitia aliquid ipsum quidem modi esse libero ullam dolorum minus quisquam sapiente consequuntur ad. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quas quod at aperiam qui repellat voluptatibus officia, cum velit asperiores aspernatur debitis, quam consequuntur perferendis incidunt expedita nulla. Ratione, nemo eius.
  </p>
 </section>

 <footer>
  <div>
   <p>&copy; 2020 cybele</p>
  </div>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it would be better practice to position nav element on top of everything then making banner behind everything, also he might encounter same problem somewhere else on other pages and then he would need to declare minus z-index on those elements again. This way nav is always on top as it should be.

Comment: I agree its probably better practice to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful also!